# libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5

I'm trying to run a python program called **Button** `python3 Button.py` but it doesn't work,  i have the next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Button.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even though i have the **libdouble-conversion.so** in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: what is your OS?, try with:  `sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion-dev`

Comment: @eyllanesc i've tried this command but it doesn't work . i'm on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What does it mean it doesn't work? Be precise: Is the package installed or not? It also gives more information about how you installed pyqt5

Comment: @eyllanesc yes the package s already installed ```libdouble-conversion-dev est déjà la version la plus récente (2.0.1-4ubuntu1). ```

Comment: how you installed pyqt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc i'v installed it using ```sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5```

Comment: @eyllanesc i did find a solution , i'm actually using this command to excute my programs ```LD_PRELOAD=/home/USR_HERE/Téléchargements/libdouble-conversion.so.1 python3 Button.py ``` , it's a problem with library

Answer (score 3):

You probably do not have libdouble-conversion.so.1 as this is not available, for instance in Ubuntu 20.04. I solved a similar problem for another program by linking the .3 library like this on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1
```

Chances are that this will also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling libdouble-conversion1 by executing `sudo apt install --reinstall libdouble-conversion1` solved the issue for me.

Reference: https://answers.ros.org/question/336354/rviz-fails-in-fresh-melodic-install-libdouble-conversion-not-found/